# Managed Dedicated Servers vs Virtual private servers vs Hosting plans

Tags: server, web-hosting

Can any body tell me what is the difference between Managed Dedicated server and Virtual private server. Similarly what is difference between Virtual Private server and hosting package? And what to use in what situation?
I read over internet but didn't get much idea of them. It would be highly appreciated if some reading material is also shared.

If the answer depends on some technology, then i am mostly using ASP.net with C# and MS SQL Server for Database operations

Answer (score 2):

With a hosting package you have the ability to upload files, create databases and easily install some common software, like wordpress. You don't have the ability, for example, to upgrade the version of Perl or PHP being used. You are sharing disk space and CPU resources with other users.

With a virtual private server the server thinks it's a real server, but is in fact sharing the same server as other VPSs. There will be limits on memory and CPU which help prevent the VPSs from, say, taking too much CPU. You can install software and configure it as much as you like.

With a managed server you have a real server all to yourself.

So it depends on how much control you want over ASP and SQLServer, and how many resources your site is going to need.

Comment: Good summary. One addition - a *managed* server is one where the hosting company is responsible for it's upkeep - usually patches, backups etc (depending on your contract).